# Access forbidden for Dependency Proxy in Gitlab CE

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce, gitlab-runner

I am trying to use the [Gitlab Dependency Proxy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/) on my on-promise instance of Gitlab CE `14.4.1` in the CI/CD jobs. I have updated the local gitlab runners to version `14.4.0`, and activated the Dependency Proxy for the shared group. When running a simple job like:

```yaml
test:
  image: ${CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX}/node:12.5.0
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get https://<my-gitlab-url>/v2/<my-group>/dependency_proxy/containers/node/manifests/12.5.0: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: no error details found in HTTP response body: "{\"message\":\"access forbidden\",\"status\":\"error\",\"http_status\":403}" (executor_docker.go:188:0s)
```

Comment: I would suggest to try it with different accounts (or impersonate someone from this group).

Comment: this is a CI/CD job, how would impersonate a user change anything? I'm not following

Comment: did you actually enable the proxy in the global gitlab-ce config file and then restart/reconfigure?

Comment: I believe that proxy is enabled by default.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann yes, and it is enabled by default as well

Comment: good to know. thanks! :)
Also: I'm out of ideas.